# Changing constraints of a Button inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

So I want to do the typical undo functionality (when the user should be able to undo, undo button appear to the right of another static label moving it to the left, and when the user can't this button dissapears and the static label returns to the right of the tableViewCell ).

I am trying to do this with a NSLayoutConstraint that changes on every cell.viewWithTag(TagOfTheUndoButton) but I am having so much trouble and not getting what i want. Is there any other possibility to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Add a Undo button in cell from storyboard with these contraints [fix (width&height),right,vertical center in container]
- add horizontal spacing between static label and button
- Create an outlet of right constraint in cell class.
- set constraint when undo clicked (to hide undo button) cell.rightConstraint.constant = cell.rightConstraint.constant + cell.btnUndo.frame.size.width
- to show undo button set the cell.rightConstraint.costant = 10(as much u space u want from right)

Comment: So you suggest to create a different cell class instead of using the default UITableViewCell in order to do that right?
Cause with default UITableViewCells i cannot create an outlet of a dynamic cell and have it different in each cell

Comment: I am not sure about the layout constraint variable creating for undoButton in cell with default UITableViewCell. can be accessed. by using tag,if it is then we can do with default cell as well.

Comment: Outlets cannot be added on a repetitive object, that's the problem

Comment: no actually we can not access the  undoButton right constraint for each cell button. I hope u understand now what i mean.